# how to remove Authorization on login route using axios and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

After creating an axios instance in the main.js file in my project,i pass the baseURL and also pass authorization header,meaning that the authorization headers will be passed in all http request.i want to remove the authorization when i try to login.

i have tried using interceptors.request to get the login url,then write a condition that if that login url is called it should delete the autorization headers.

This is my instace

```
const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://eelspace.herokuapp.com/api/v1/",
  headers: { Authorization: "Token" + " " + localStorage.getItem("token") }
});
```

this is the part where i get the url of login and then i try to delete that headers

```
base.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  let url = request.url;
  if (url === "auth/login/") {
    // console.log(base.defaults.headers);
    delete base.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  }
  console.log(url);
  return request;
});
```

After running the code..it still doesn't work

Comment: Why not just use axios instead delete the interceptor header?

Comment: i dont get this

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Maybe this thread can help you https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382

Comment: Are you sure `url === "auth/login/"` result is true?

Comment: can you create a js fiddle or something?

Comment: Thanks guys i have solved this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go with this:

```js
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      // if request is not login or registration, set base url and add token to header
      if (!config.url.includes('login') && !config.url.includes('registration')) {
        // before request is sent
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
      }
      return config
    },
    error => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )
```

For this particular case, I only set the auth header after I check for both the registration and login URLs. if they are not any of those, I add the authorization header. Let me know if you need further clarification.